# Flask app not compatible with Buildpack Python heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have Flask application that I want to apply to Heroku.

I have made a Procfile as such:

```
web: gunicorn routes:app
```

and a requirements.txt:

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12
gunicorn==19.6.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

but whenever I try to run the command:

```
git push heroku master
```

I always get this error:`App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz

even though I have set the buildpack to python. My main python file is called `routes.py`, so the Profile should be correct, and I have made a lot of research and all the dependencies seems to be there, what could be the issue?

for all my dependencies I also have a Pipfile and a Pipfile.lock..

I tried using `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

and this resulted in this error:

```
 No matching distribution found for adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4 (from -r /tmp/build_622384b275f7a5f640333152a3b25ba1/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

output of Git Status:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Errors i get from my requirements.txt

```
       File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
     import distutils.core
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 16, in <module>
     from distutils.dist import Distribution
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 9, in <module>
     import re
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
     class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
 AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

 ----------------------------------------
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oqscorl3/enum34/
 Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

Comment: Can you paste the full output of `git status` when run from your project root?

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: sorry I'm not seeing the result of `git status`. It looks like you ran a pip install command, but `git` is different. Can you try again? Please paste the command you type and the result you get so we can see everything...

Comment: oh sorry i updated it now

Comment: thanks, now can you please add the contents of `.gitignore` (if any)? And for sanity testing, can you try `heroku buildpacks:clear` then `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python` just to be sure. @baileyhaldwin better yet, if you can make a github gist with all your files that can save time. There are a few moving parts to this kind of situation...

Comment: Thank you. Since this is only for testing purposes, i have no [.gitignore] file. I ran the two commands, but the same problem occurs..

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 btw, and I got a lot of errors, from the requirements.txt file, and it can detect the Python application, but I get some errors, regarding python setup.py egg-Info, maybe I have a wrong requirements.txt file? I just used pip freeze (using a virtual environment), to get the newest version, however, errors still occur?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179127/discussion-between-duhaime-and-baileyhaldwin).

Answer (score 0):

When I recently received similar errors, I was able to drop the version numbers from my requirements.txt to get a successful deploy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still seeking an answer, it appears the requirements.txt is missing dependency `adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4` as stated in the error message. The package doesn't exist on PyPI, so `pip install` won't work. That's why the deployment failed.

In this case, it's often helpful to run `pip freeze` again to see if any new dependency caused error.
If nothing helps, better do a clean reinstall of everything:

```sh
rm -rf venv
python -m venv venv
pip install DEPENDENCY-NAME
```

Then try deploying again.